# Find getElementById property in window.document

Tags: html, dom

Summary: I wanted to know if there was a way to open console in chrome, type window, go to document and search for the getElementById method

Reason: I was searching around and found a lot of the CSS styles for an element(see picture 1 below) and was curious if methods like getElementById were displayed as well

What I tried:

1) I tried looking searching for the getElementById by control + f and searched for "get"

2) Tried seeing if I could get info from mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/Document

3) Tried reading the link pasted on mdn https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nonelementparentnode

Still couldn't find it though :/

[element css styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wvAF.png)

[window.document properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzA3w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right (directly - how to find 'getElementById' property within global Window object) it is possible to do. You should write in the console `Window`, open `document`, then `__proto__` (should be the last property of the `document` object), then `__proto__` again, and now you can find `getElementById` method here. The reason is `Window` object quite difficult, and uses prototypes to keep all inherit properties and methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: Thanks! I just verified in microsoft edge, then went to chrome and show that it was there. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the elements with a defined id doing right click-> inspect element-> console
and then `document.querySelectorAll('*[id]')`

but based on picture two, you want to retrieve the class name that starts with "google_"

then do `document.querySelectorAll('google_');`

or can you please clarify the question? maybe I'm not getting it right

Comment: Thanks for the info Erick! Sorry for writing the question weirdly. Bogdan Chernovol and aprouja1 were able to answer the question the way I intended to ask it. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `console.dir(document.__proto__.__proto__)` as it is in the overall prototype of the document

Comment: Nice, just tested in browser and this works as well, thanks!